# Get array of multiple substrings preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have to iterate 300 files and change a string from being in one column to 4 columns in excel.. I know there is a way to do this in reg-ex but I can not figure it out... I know that preg_match can name returned matches.. but I have tried to use regex101.com to figure out how to get the returned results I'm looking for..

i have this string..

```
Rev 1: blah blah blah blah blah blah 1/1/2017 BLAH
```

and i have to get it into an array that looks like this...

```
$results = array(
    "rev" => "Rev 1",
    "text" => "blah blah blah blah blah blah",
    "date" => "1/1/2017"
    "name" => "BLAH"
)
```

the issue that I'm faced with, is I don't know how to get multiple matches in one preg_match call to return the desired way.. I have tried to Google some ways to do this, and have come up empty.

I have some regex that match each string separtly.. but not all at once.

`\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \(?[A-z]+\)?` matches the `date` and the `name` with or without the `()` around it

`^([Rr][Ee][Vv] \d+:)` matches the `rev`

I do not know of a way to get the `text` between the `rev` and the `date` so I do not have reg-ex for that...

Comment: Nothing will be fool-proof.  What if something that looks like a date appears in the text?

Comment: i have personally when though all 300+ sheets and checked all that when i copied the text from a excel comment to a new tab. so i know that there was nothing like that. and if there is, than so be it, im going to go though them all one at a time and double check, cause when i run this script it will save them into a new dir and not overwrite the original files. but yes you are right, for others this might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close (caveat here: I'm assuming all your strings will be the same format)

```
^([Rr][Ee][Vv] \d+:)(.*)\d+\/\d+\/\d+(.*)?
```

The `(.*)` lets you capture what's between the groups. You should put anything you want captured inside parenthesis.

You can see it in action here https://regex101.com/r/8GKgWl/1

Comment: ahhh, see `(.*)` was the missing link, i knew there was a way, haha thank you!

Comment: returns false for some reason.... 
https://regex101.com/r/8GKgWl/3
works fine there though